# Problem with strong Typisation in Pattern Matching

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, pattern-matching, strong-typing

I want to write a recursive function, that uses pattern matching.
I want to call it with an array-string (like for example that one ["01!", "1!!?", "?!1"]). If the head of the first element is a 1 , the function shall quit, if the head is 0 it shall remove the element from the list, and if the element is ? or ! it shall restart the function with the next string of the array (there's going to be another function later, I just want to get it working so far).

```
may_convergent:: [[Char]] -> String
may_convergent [] = "empty list"
may_convergent (x:xs)
       | head x == "1" = "May-convergent "
       | head x == "0" = tail x
       | otherwise = may_convergent xs
```

That's my code so far. When I execute it , I get a Typisation error. 
Can someone explain to me how I get the Typisation right in the first line of the Code ?
The error message says that the expected Type is [[[Char]]] but when I correct the Typisation and call on the function it doesnt work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `head x` is a `char`, since `x` is a string`, so `head x == "0"` makes no sense.

Comment: Please never update questions in a way that invalidates existing answers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I will keep that in mind

Comment: Likewise if you have a followup question to ask, please ask it as a new Question, rather than trying to start a back-and-forth on this one (referring here to the "now it works but I have another problem" update). Stack Overflow works best with focused questions that have a definite finish. I've edited that update out, but you can find it in the post history if it is helpful to you when asking your new question.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the types of the involved quantities:

```
x :: [Char]
head x :: Char
"1" :: String
```

hence `head x == "1"` is trying to compare a character and a string. A correctly typed comparison would be

```
head x == '1'
```

since we have `'1' :: Char`.

That being said, note that `head x` will crash when `x` is empty. For that reason it's better to avoid using `head` and `tail`, and use pattern matching instead.

```
may_convergent:: [[Char]] -> String
may_convergent []            = "empty list"
may_convergent (('1':_ ):_ ) = "May-convergent "
may_convergent (('0':ys):_ ) = ys
may_convergent (_       :xs) = may_convergent xs
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I now use pattern Matching and tried to check if there are ?s or !s in the head of the strings using it. I compared it using characters instead of strings , as you did in your example, but my code doesn't compile if I execute it like this and I don't get why. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The pattern `(('!':xs):('?':_):_)` requires that, in the list of strings, the first string starts with ! and the second string starts with ?. Is that what you really want? You might instead want to use two separate lines, one for handling ! and another for ?. It's hard to tell what you actually need.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with the type system. But with your checks. If you write:

```
head x == "1"
```

Haskell derives that the type of `head x` should be a `String`, and hence that `x` should be a `[String]`. But since `x` is the first element of your list, it is a `String`, not a `[String]`. You can fix this by comparing with a character, like:

```
head x == '1'
```

We can however use pattern matching here, making the code not only more elegant, but more safe as well. For example even if your current code would compile, it would raise an error on `[""]`, since `head ""` of course makes no sense.

We can define a function like:

```
may_convergent:: [[Char]] -> String
may_convergent [] = "empty list"
may_convergent (('1':_):_) = "May-convergent "
may_convergent (('0':xs):_) = xs
may_convergent (_:xs) = may_convergent xs
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I modified my Code using pattern matching.
It now looks like this:

may_convergent:: [[Char]] -> String
may_convergent [] = "empty list"
may_convergent (('1':_):_) = "May-convergent "
may_convergent (('0':xs):y) = y
may_convergent (('!':xs):('?':_):_) = may_convergent xs

But the code doesnt compile because I get an error because of the last line. I don't get why, because I'm now comparing the head with a character instead of a string.

Comment: @T.Naz: because you call `may_convergent` with `xs`, but `xs` is the "tail" of the first item, so a `String`, not a `[String]`. You likely want to use `may_convergent (('!':_):('?':_):xs)`.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, actually I wanna call may_convergent xs, so on the String after the '!' or '?'

Comment: @T.Naz: but your `may_convergent` takes as input a `[[Char]]`, or a `[String]` (this is the same), so that makes not much sense.